# How to download album shared with me on Google+?

Tags: google-plus-photos

How do I download an album that's been shared with me on Google+?

I've read these instructions on [Google support](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2710716):

> 1. From your stream or someone's profile, click on the name of the shared album you'd like to download.
> 2. Click the  dropdown icon > Download album.

However, I don't seem to have the *Download album* option. I've only got *View post activity*, *Mute post*, and *Report this post*.

Answer (score 4):

If the pictures have really been assembled into an album by the user (rather than, for example, just aggregated by Google+ for a particular day), then:

1. Go to the person's profile page;
2. Find the album in the Photos section;
3. Click the down arrow in the top-right corner of the album frame;
4. Click "Download" (see image below).

This will open a dialog to save a ZIP file containing all of the images in that album.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @JoeDeRose. In the image you enclosed - where it says "download" for you, it says "slideshow" for me... any idea why?

Comment: Same for me. I think Google has removed that option. :(